# Get all the related datasets, LS, pipelines, and resources related to a pipeline in Azure Data Factory

Tags: development-environment, azure-rm-template, azure-data-factory

I am trying to migrate a pipeline from a data factory with pipelines/ds/ls related to other pipelines. To do this, I want to find all the related ds/ls/resources to the pipeline that I want to migrate to a different data factory(differnet env). What would be the way to do so? Secondly, how would you do it using ARM Template in release pipelines?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply accomplish this task by importing/exporting ARM templates. This will export your datasets, Linked Services and pipelines settings. But if you are changing your data source and destination, you need to change them separately.

To export the pipeline configuration as a template just go to that pipeline and click on **three dots** on right side and click on **Export template** option.

[image]

Comment: exporting the pipeline template does not import related datasets,linkedlist,triggers,dataflow.